# How to assign variable if Cursor returns Bit of 0

Tags: t-sql, cursor

I have written a cursor to search through a table looking at one bit value. 
If all values are 1, I send an email. But if one value is 0 in any row, I don't send the email. The issue that I am having comes in my If statement. In SSMS, "@isComplete = 0" is breaking with only an "Incorrect syntax" error. I am not sure what I am missing here. My code is below. Thank you.

```
-------------------------------------------------
-- Start the INNER Cursor --
-------------------------------------------------
DECLARE @Complete int

DECLARE @isComplete Bit = 1

DECLARE INNERCur CURSOR FOR
SELECT Complete 
FROM #AAEAPVS

OPEN INNERCur
FETCH NEXT FROM INNERCur INTO @Complete
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
   BEGIN
      If @Complete = 0
          BEGIN
            @isComplete = 0
          END
      FETCH NEXT FROM INNERCur INTO @Complete
   END
CLOSE InnerCurs
DEALLOCATE InnerCurs
-------------------------------------------------
-- INNER Curser END --
-------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The incorrect syntax is that you need to use SET to assign the variable value, so change

```
@isComplete = 0
```

to

```
SET @isComplete = 0
```

And assuming you want to exit as soon as you find something that is not complete you should change your WHILE condition to

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @isComplete = 1
```

But most important of all, you probably don't need to use a cursor at all - you should avoid cursors in SQL if possible. You can probably just do something like this

```
DECLARE @isComplete Bit = 1
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM #AAEAPVS WHERE Complete = 0)
BEGIN
    SET @isComplete = 0
END
```

and even that is more than you need, you can do it in a single statement

```
DECLARE @isComplete Bit = 1
SELECT @isComplete = 0 FROM #AAEAPVS WHERE Complete = 0
```

Comment: Thank you. That answers my question perfectly. And I am getting rid of the cursor. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error results from not having a statement on the line. You need to use either SET or SELECT to assign a value to a variable, e.g. `set @isComplete = 0`.

Why, pray tell, a cursor rather than a simple EXISTS query? A far more efficient solution is:

```
select @isComplete = case
  when exists ( select 42 from #AAEAPVS where Complete = 0 ) then 0
  else 1 end;
```

Tip: It is helpful to tag database questions with both the appropriate software (MySQL, Oracle, DB2, ...) and version, e.g. sql-server-2014. Differences in syntax and features often affect the answers.